# AWS EC2 instance losing GPU support after reboot

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, kernel, gpu, nvidia

Rebooting an instance on tuesday, I first ran into the problem of losing GPU support on a AWS p2.xlarge machine with the Ubuntu Deep Learning AMI.

I tested it three times now on two days and a collegue had the same problem, so I guess it is a AWS bug. Though maybe someone has an idea how to debug it better.

**Basically, after shutdown and reboot, the instance no longer has the nvidia module loaded in the kernel. Furthermore, according to dmesg, there seems to be a different kernel loaded. All of this happens without me actively causing it.**

Here are the steps to reproduce the problem using a fresh instance and **no custom code**. I am working in Ireland (eu-west-1), the instance was launched in the Availability Zone eu-west-1a:

- Launched an instance with the "Deep Learning AMI (Ubuntu) Version
  21.2 (ami-0e9085a8d461c2d01)
- Instance type: p2.xlarge, all defaults
- Logged into instance, only ran the following four commands:

```
ubuntu@...:~$ lsmod | grep nvidia
nvidia              16592896  0
ipmi_msghandler        49152  1 nvidia
```

```
dmesg | less
...
[    0.000000] Linux version 4.4.0-1075-aws (buildd@lgw01-amd64-035) (gcc version 5.4.0 20160609 (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.10) ) #85-Ubuntu SMP Thu Jan 17 17:15:12 UTC 2019 (Ubuntu 4.4.0-1075.85-aws 4.4.167)
[    0.000000] Command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-1075-aws root=UUID=96950bba-70e8-4a4b-9d78-d2bc1c767e04 ro console=tty1 console=ttyS0 nvme.io_timeout=4294967295
...
```

```
ubuntu@...:~$ nvidia-smi
Tue Mar 19 16:41:53 2019
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 410.79       Driver Version: 410.79       CUDA Version: 10.0     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  Tesla K80           On   | 00000000:00:1E.0 Off |                    0 |
| N/A   42C    P8    32W / 149W |      0MiB / 11441MiB |      0%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+

+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                       GPU Memory |
|  GPU       PID   Type   Process name                             Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|  No running processes found                                                 |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

```
ubuntu@...:~$ sudo shutdown now
```

- The instance does not shut down right away, maybe it is running updates that however I have NOT actively triggered.
- After the state showed "stopped", started the instance again via the AWS Management Console
- Ran the first three commands:

```
ubuntu@...:~$ lsmod | grep nvidia
(no output)
```

```
dmesg | less
...
[    0.000000] Linux version 4.4.0-1077-aws (buildd@lcy01-amd64-021) (gcc version 5.4.0 20160609 (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.10) ) #87-Ubuntu SMP Wed Mar 6 00:03:05 UTC 2019 (Ubuntu 4.4.0-1077.87-aws 4.4.170)
[    0.000000] Command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-1077-aws root=UUID=96950bba-70e8-4a4b-9d78-d2bc1c767e04 ro console=tty1 console=ttyS0 nvme.io_timeout=4294967295
...
```

```
ubuntu@...:~$ nvidia-smi
NVIDIA-SMI has failed because it couldn't communicate with the NVIDIA driver. Make sure that the latest NVIDIA driver is installed and running.
```

How could I force to boot with the kernel 4.4.0-1075-aws? Since it is hvm virtualization, I cannot choose a kernel directly in the dialog.

Comment: I'm having exactly same problem at eu-central (Frankfurt). Happens with p2.xlarge and p3.2xlarge instances with Deep Learning AMI (Ubuntu) Version 21.2. So far no help, only terminating that instance and starting a new one from scratch which is huge pain in the ass due to downloading all the data from s3.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There seems to be a problem with building older NVIDIA drivers on 4.4.0-107x-aws kernels. You can install newer NVIDIA drivers, which should work fine with the current kernel:

```
wget http://us.download.nvidia.com/tesla/410.104/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-410.104.run
sudo sh ./NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-410.104.run --no-drm --disable-nouveau --dkms --silent --install-libglvnd
```

According to an AWS representative, the drivers were updated in the Deep Learning AMI on 21/03/2019 [[AWS forums](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=894100&tstart=0)].

Comment: Thanks @Mito, fixed now.

Comment: Thank you, @alkamid. I just tested the new image and it seems to work: It boots directly with the 4.4.0-1077-aws kernel but has the nvidia module mounted. This stays the same after a reboot. Since I no longer have a 'broken' instance, I cannot test the driver update but for me, it works now with a new instance.

Comment: I do not know why, but `sudo sh ./NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-410.104.run` worked for me, when I used the command line options, I only got ERRORs.

Comment: experienced the nvidia broken with g4dn.xlarge ubuntu server reboot syndrome. solved it with the copy-pasta dance with https://docs.nvidia.com/datacenter/tesla/tesla-installation-notes/index.html#ubuntu-lts

Answer (score 4):

I experienced the same issue and it helped me to do

```
sudo apt-get install nvidia-cuda-toolkit
sudo reboot
```

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I experienced the same issue on an AWS G5 instance running `Amazon Linux 2 AMI (HVM) - Kernel 5.10, SSD` with the latest NVIDIA driver (which as of the time of this post is version 535.129.03).

This doesn't happen after every restart, but rather sporadically. This is probably the 4th time it happened to me in the last 3-4 months.

What worked was to simply reinstall the driver (this assumes that all prerequisites for the driver have been met and will likely not work if you are doing a fresh install on a new instance):

```
# Make sure the instance has the AmazonS3ReadOnlyAccess policy
$ aws s3 cp --recursive s3://ec2-linux-nvidia-drivers/latest/ . \
  && chmod +x NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64*.run \
  && sudo CC=/usr/bin/gcc10-cc ./NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64*.run --silent
```

Then verify that the install went all right:

```
$ nvidia-smi
Thu Nov  2 10:04:01 2023       
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 535.129.03             Driver Version: 535.129.03   CUDA Version: 12.2     |
|-----------------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name                 Persistence-M | Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp   Perf          Pwr:Usage/Cap |         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|                                         |                      |               MIG M. |
|=========================================+======================+======================|
|   0  NVIDIA A10G                    On  | 00000000:00:1B.0 Off |                    0 |
...
```

Finally, reboot:

```
sudo reboot
```

Answer (score 0):

In amazon p3 ec2 machine build from image
with Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS
I had to do:

```
sudo apt-get install nvidia-cuda-toolkit
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-drivers-common
sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall
sudo reboot
```

Terveisin, Markus